# How can += be used when adding to an object property that may not exist?

Tags: javascript

Consider an array of objects

```
myArray = [
  {date: 'date1', amount: 1},
  {date: 'date1', amount: 2},
  {date: 'date2', amount: 3},
  {date: 'date2', amount: 4},
]
```

I want to end up with values summed in a object like so:

```
{
  date1: 3,
  date2: 7
}
```

This works:

```
let myObj = {}
myArray.forEach(arrayObj=>{
  myObj[arrayObj.date] ? myObj[arrayObj.date] += arrayObj.amount : myObj[arrayObj.date] = obj.amount
})
```

This would be cleaner but does not work

```
let myObj = {}
myArray.forEach(arrayObj=>{
  myObj[arrayObj.date] += arrayObj.amount
})
```

Question: is there a way to do this without checking for the existence of the property?

Comment: You could pre-fill `myObj` with `0`s, like `let myObj = { date1: 0, date2: 0 };`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get around repeating `myObj[arrayObj.date]` twice, but you can make things shorter by unconditionally assigning to it, and alternating `||` it with 0.

```js
myArray = [
  {date: 'date1', amount: 1},
  {date: 'date1', amount: 2},
  {date: 'date2', amount: 3},
  {date: 'date2', amount: 4},
]
const result = {};
for (const { date, amount } of myArray) {
  result[date] = (result[date] || 0) + amount;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Better to use the nullish coalescing operator `??` since that's precisely its use case (IMO).

Comment: It's an option, but `||` works just as well in this situation, and people are less familiar with it so it has the potential to confuse, and it's less compatible with browsers

Comment: If you're worried about IE or Opera Mini, I guess... https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing. And if no one uses it in samples, no one gets familiar with it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Especially when counting with numbers, `??` is a better solution that marks clearly we're interested in defaulting `undefined` not `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to create a `DefaultDict` object, similar to that in [python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). `DefaultDict` returns a predefined value for missing keys, instead of `undefined`.

```js
function DefaultDict(value) {
    return new Proxy({}, {
        get(target, key) {
            return key in target ? target[key] : value
        }
    })
}

// example:


myArray = [
  {date: 'date1', amount: 1},
  {date: 'date1', amount: 2},
  {date: 'date2', amount: 3},
  {date: 'date2', amount: 4},
]

myObj = DefaultDict(0)

myArray.forEach(v => myObj[v.date] += v.amount)

console.log(myObj)
```